# Quick bookks sdk emaill cc

Tags: vb.net, sdk, quickbooks

I am trying to send an email with vb and I want to send them to our customers. We have the email as our customer and the "Cc" as the customers accounting department. I can easily get the eamil but I can not get the "Cc" or other alternate contact info. I have tried query through the Icustmomqury object and get anything for the extended contact info,

Comment: And your question would be?

Comment: Post your code. Post the XML response from QuickBooks. Post *something* that someone could actually use to help you.